# C# Hashset<string> Contains incorrectly returns false

Tags: c#, database, string

I am trying to compare a Hashset of strings populated from a database against a string property from an object. I know that it exists in the hashset, but it is always returning false.

Oddly enough, I wrote a test program that behaves how I would expect. See Below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "A";
        HashSet<String>[] array = new HashSet<string>[1]; 
        array[0] = new HashSet<string>();
       Boolean isA = true;
       Boolean isB = false;
       array[0].Add("A");
        if (array[0].Contains(test) && isA || isB)
            if (test.Equals("A")) {
                Console.WriteLine("A");
            }
            return;
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, this does not. Do I have to write a custom comparator for this? This is not a custom object, I'm just comparing strings. I know that the string is contained in the hash set.

```
private readonly HashSet<string>[] cars = new HashSet<string>[5];

 for (int i = 0; i < cars.Length; i++)
        cars[i] = new HashSet<string>();

  foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
        switch (dr[0].ToString())
         {
            case "1": 
              cars[0].Add(dr[1].ToString());
                            break;
          }
    }
bool test = cars[0].Contains("A"); //Always returns false
```

Comment: You add `1` and wonder why `A` is not found? What does the debugger say is in the HashSet?

Comment: I know that "A" exists in the hash set. The debugger confirms that.

Comment: Then show the exact code, exact input, exact contents. If your attempt at [mcve] shows no error, the error most likely is elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add with it `cars[0].Add(dr[1].ToString().Trim().ToUpper())` and check.